# Filtering list based on array columns to create a [dict(str:list)] result

Tags: pandas, list, filter

My table looks like this(df):

| category | product_in_cat |
| --- | --- |
| cat1 | [A,B,C] |
| cat2 | [E,F,G] |

"category" is str, and product_in_cat is list type. I have a list:product=[A,B,G]
I want to get a final [dict(str:list)] looks like:

[{cat1:[A,B]},{cat2:[G]}]

I think I can use below code:

```
list1=[]
for inde,row in df.iterrows():
        list1.append.({row['category']:row['product_in_cat'] in product})
```

I know this part is not correct,`row['product_in_cat'] in product` but I am not sure how to filter out the list column base on the given "product" list. Please help, and thank you in advance!

Comment: "product" list is external list or column in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) to find the common part of two lists:

```py
import numpy as np


df_ = df['product_in_cat'].apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x, product).tolist())
l = [{k: v} for k, v in zip(df['category'], df_)]
```

```
print(l)

[{'cat1': ['A', 'B']}, {'cat2': ['G']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert each list in the column to a set and use `intersection` with the external product list:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['A','B','G']
data = {'category':['cat 1','cat 2'],
        'product_in_cat': [ ['A','B','C'] ,['E','F','G']]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
dict(zip(df['category'],df['product_in_cat'].apply(lambda x: set(x).intersection(lst))))

#output
{'cat 1': {'A', 'B'}, 'cat 2': {'G'}}
```